# System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll error

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

---

> Parser Error  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs"
>   Inherits="PMP.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

---

Yesterday, I shut up my Windows 7, an Windows update was pending there without any process for nearly one hour, then I shut my laptop. When I re-opened my Windows 7 and ran the PMP MVC application, this error occurred. I finished that pending windows update. That did not fix the issue.

I googled to find that should re-install .net framework 1.1/2.1, I tried but nothing good happened. This error always here. I spent 4 hrs re-installing VS 2010, but it didn't resolve the issue.

How can I fix this issue?

[Update]:

I tried this,

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\gacutil.exe" /i Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/System.EnterpriseServices.dll

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\gacutil.exe" /i Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
```

to found that `gacutil.exe` in v6.0A is 0kb. Then replace the file in `v7.0A` to `v6.0A`. This didn't solve the issue either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the file `System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll`

from

`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`

to

`C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_System.EnterpriseServices_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_2.0.0.0_x-ww_7d5f3790\`

Comment: Be careful when manually moving DLLs. You'll usually cause more issues for yourself down the road.

Answer (score 27):

This happened to me when I had installed windows updates (and .Net 4.5.2 update) but was putting off the restart. Restarting my computer and thus allowing the updates to finalize fixed the issue.

Comment: Surprisingly enough restart did it for me.

Comment: Suspected that was the issue, thanks for the confirmation.  Thanks, SMS/pushed updates.

Comment: I had the same problem after installing 4.6.2 and putting off the restart

Comment: same here. it happened while "Reliability Rollup for Microsoft.NET Framework 4.5.2, 4.6 and 4.6.1" (KB3179930) was waiting to install. a reboot fixed it for me too

Comment: StackOverflow to the rescue, again!  i installed some updates and restarted, and the problem was still there, but there were more updates to install afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the

`System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll`

by installing .NET `framework 3.5.`

The `Framework 3.0` caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on this for weeks. Tried the file moving. Tried deleting bin. Tried deleting nuget files. Tried reinstalling all dotnet frameworks, all dotnet core sdks/runtimes. Tried Admin. Tried reopening solution. Restarted my computer 100 times. Tried VS 2019 and 2017.

(On Windows 10)
The only thing that ended up working was Reinstalling Windows. Settings -> Recovery -> Get Started -> Keep my files.

Answer (score 0):

delete bin folder in project, then rebuilt it.

Answer (score 0):

In one case, the System.EnterpriseServices.dll had been checked into version control and was read only.  Simply deleting that individual dll and rebuilding fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

run Visual Studio as Administrator works for me

Answer (score 0):

For me , I just close the solution and reopen. Its  solved.

Answer (score 0):

I just stop `IIS Express` and run again my application.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but the gacutil trick worked for me. Note - open Developer Command Prompt as Administrator.