# Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I run a new web application in Visual Studio 2010, I'm getting a "Could not load file or assembly System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'" error message.

Here's the complete text of the error message:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> #### Parser Error
>
> **Description:** An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> **Parser Error Message:**  Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies.  An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> Line 1: <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.Global" Language="C#" %>
>
> **Source File**: /global.asax **Line:** 1

[image: Screenshot of error message (transcribed above)]

What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Please paste the error description

Comment: "having an issue" means what, exactly?  Are you getting a runtime error?  A build error?  Can you post the exception and a code sample, or at least specify what sort of problem you're having?

Comment: do you get any compilation error?

Comment: There is no error , I just create new project , and i am having this issue while running

Comment: Did you change the .NET Framework version the site is running under?

Comment: Found this solution: http://phxthunder.blogspot.com/2010/03/systementerpriseservices-exception-when.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project contains a broken reference to the file 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'; You may also try by re-installing the .NET Framework.

See these links for similar type of problems : [System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890773/system-enterpriseservices-wrapper-dll-error)
And

http://help.turbolaw.com/entries/361597-error-message-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-enterpriseservices-wrapper-dll-when-starting-tu