# Linked Service error : 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' not found

Tags: azure-data-factory

When trying to create linked service in azure data factory which uses the Microsoft integration run time (self-hosted), the connection test throws error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."
[screenshot with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAylo.png)
This is for copy activity in azure data factory which will have source db as an on-premise SQL db, self-hosted integration runtime is set up and running successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll or one of its dependencies

Since self-hosted integration runtime is set up and running successfully, this error may be caused by the environment of on-premise. You could try to re-install .net framework or follow below similar solutions:

1.[System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890773/system-enterpriseservices-wrapper-dll-error)

2.[Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356058/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-enterpriseservices-wrapper-dll)