# Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' is not a valid Win32 application in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, dll, wrapper

I am using MVC app having .net 4.5 and it was working fine in, 4 days back windows 10 update has happened and my IIS setting has gone.

After that i couldn't able to run my MVC app in Visual studio and it starts giving

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. 
>   is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)

Every time, and don't understand what could be the reason, i searched so many posts, links, solutions are like moving dlls, etc.

Can somebody give my what is the reason and how can solve it

Comment: but none the answers are working for me..

Answer (score 0):

this might help [system enterprice services error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890773/system-enterpriseservices-wrapper-dll-error)

Also, it might be worth re-installing the latest updates to Visual Studio as these often get corrupted on operating system updates.

Comment: i didn't update any VS updates, i did only windows 10 updates....can it be the problem ?? what if i uninstall the latest update for windows10 ??

Comment: I'd just re-install the VS updates first, this will be the easier solution since at some point in the future you will probably need the windows 10 update and/or it might auto install again anyway.