# Loss of System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll

Tags: c++, dll, windows-xp

I am currently running the system on Windows XP - yes I know it is outdated. We had a program installed years ago that was designed to work on Windows XP and this week I had to take my hard drives out the computer and transfer to another mother board and most of the things are working except when I now try and log into my application it tells me that `System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll` or another path is missing - but they are still there.

I have copied the file from system to the **winsxs** folder as well but nothing is coming up.

Comment: Update your question with exact error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890773/system-enterpriseservices-wrapper-dll-error)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/missing-not-found-error/dll/windows/microsoft/msdn-disc-4455-01/system-enterpriseservices-wrapper-dll/

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.